# Chrome extension: chrome local storage is not set instantly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am having strange issues with Chrome Local storage setting and retrieval.

In `background.js` I am setting it when a certain URL's HTML is fetched once the page loading is completed and then in `content.js` I am fetching values from local storage. At times it is stored and fetched instantly while other times `results.html` is `undefined`. And if I use `chrome.storage.local.clear()` it makes it more worst, make you to refresh the page 2-3 times at least. Below is my code:

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    async function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        // Reset storage
        // chrome.storage.local.clear() // it is lagging refreshing values
        sendResponse("bar")
        // Check whether it is correct URL
        var url = 'http://localhost:8000/get.php?url='+request
        console.log('URL for AJAX =',url)
        var result = await sendReq(url)
        var json_result  = JSON.parse(result)
        var status = json_result['status'] 
        var rules = []
        console.log('Status = '+status)

        if(status == 'ok') {
            rules = json_result['msg']['rules']
            chrome.storage.local.set({'rules': rules}, function() {}); 
            
            url = 'http://localhost:8000/read.php?url='+request
            result = await sendReq(url)
            // console.log(result)
            chrome.storage.local.set({'html': result}, function() {}); // this goes undefined if the URL of visiting page is changed.
        } else {
            // To check on content script
            chrome.storage.local.set({'html': '__FAIL__'}, function() {}); 
        }
    }
);
```

**content.js** (Using JQuery)

```
  $(function() {
    // console.clear()
    console.log('The Agile Super Cluster extension cleared all previous output')
    chrome.storage.local.get(['html','rules'], function(result) {
        // Do not perform things below if it is not a relevant Super Cluster URL
        if(result.html == '__FAIL__' || typeof (result.html) == 'undefined') {
          return
        }
      .....

// Out of onReady() block
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
        url,
        function (response) {
            console.log('Sending Response')
            console.log(response);
        }
    );
```

Comment: [`.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/set) is asynchronous and returns a promise. You'll need to wait for it to resolve via `await`, `.then()`, etc.

Comment: @Ouroborus I am storing locally, plus, official documentation example says it is optional

Comment: Waiting on async tasks is technically optional, yes. However, if you wish to use the results of that task, you need to wait for it to have results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use messaging *correctly* so you can wait on the result reliably.

1. remove chrome.storage, it's not necessary for this task;
2. remove `async` from onMessage listener ([why?](/a/53024910)) and use a separate async function to get info;
3. return the result via `sendResponse` + `return true`.

content.js:

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(url, res => {
  console.log(res);
  if (res.html) {
    // use `res.html` here
  }
});
```

background.js:

```js
const API_GET = 'http://localhost:8000/get.php?url=';
const API_READ = 'http://localhost:8000/read.php?url=';

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  getInfo(request).then(sendResponse);
  return true; // keep the channel open for asynchronous sendResponse
});

async function getInfo(url) {
  const res = JSON.parse(await sendReq(`${API_GET}${url}`));
  return res.status === 'ok' ? {
    rules: res.msg.rules,
    html: await sendReq(`${API_READ}${url}`),
  } : {};
}
```

Comment: You made it very clear and compressed. Actually I wanted to use messaging and if you remember I asked you question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72846615/chrome-extension-uncaught-in-promise-error-could-not-establish-connection-r?noredirect=1#comment128669091_72846615) as I was having issue to use it from background.js file. I will now build things up based on your suggestions.